.NET Core removes headers in Exception handler
I have tried to add couple of headers in a response when I got an exception, but as I understood, Kestrel removes all headers if you add them if add them in IExceptionHandler's implementation.
Does anybody have any idea about it?
internal class CustomExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var traceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var interactionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var clientIp = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString() ?? "Unknown";

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        
        context.Response.Headers["X-Client-IP"] = clientIp;
        context.Response.Headers["trace-id"] = traceId;
        context.Response.Headers["interaction-id"] = interactionId;

        var errorResponse = new
        {
            StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
            Message = "An unexpected error occurred.",
            TraceId = traceId,
            InteractionId = interactionId
        };

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(errorResponse), cancellationToken);
        return false;
    }
}

I added a simple response logging middleware class. When I added it, then the following method doesn't work:
context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Append("X-Client-IP", clientIp);
            context.Response.Headers.Append("trace-id", traceId);
            context.Response.Headers.Append("interaction-id", interactionId);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

app.UseMiddleware<ResponseLoggingMiddleware1>();

public class ResponseLoggingMiddleware1
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ResponseLoggingMiddleware1> _logger;

    public ResponseLoggingMiddleware1(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ResponseLoggingMiddleware1> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Create a memory stream to capture the response body
        var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = memoryStream;

            // Continue processing the request
            await _next(context);

            // Log the response information
            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var responseBody = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation($"Response Status: {context.Response.StatusCode}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Response Body: {responseBody}");

            // Reset the body stream position and copy it to the original body stream
            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
        }
    }
}

I found it. Problem is related to ResponseLoggingMiddleware. It tries to read closed memory.
public class ResponseLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ResponseLoggingMiddleware> _logger;

    public ResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ResponseLoggingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Preserve the original response body stream
        var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

        try
        {
            // Use a memory stream to capture the response
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.Response.Body = memoryStream;

                // Call the next middleware in the pipeline
                await _next(context);

                // Read the response stream and log it
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var responseBody = await new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEndAsync();

                // Log response details
                _logger.LogInformation($"Response Status: {context.Response.StatusCode}");
                _logger.LogInformation($"Response Body: {responseBody}");

                // Copy the response body back to the original stream
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Restore the original response body stream
            context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;
        }
    }
}


What is your issue exaxctly ? Where did you see that kestrel removes handlers ?

Do u have such a setting? .UseKestrel(option => option.AddServerHeader = false); Maybe that is why u don't see the headers...

I found problem but dont have  a clue :) When I add a simple response logger middleware then response onstarting method is not working

problem is when I get an error then response logging mid. tries to read closed memory. I changed mid. and now it is working.
